# Creating dynamic templates with GAS

Tags: scripting, google-apps-script

We've just decided to purchase Google Apps for Business for a couple of users and are now running pilot for migration.

We have a certain issue, which we would like to see if it can be solved with Google Apps Script.

**Suppose that the following situation applies:**

At this moment we're in a domain and we have certain user templates set-up in documents such as a document for faxing and a document for memo's. These templates have application-logic behind them so the template gets filled in values for the users name, and branch office, ...
What we would like to do is replicate this behaviour in Google Drive, but I'm not sure what the best way is to implement such a feature.

Do we create a spreadsheet and in the script editor we write the full template from scratch? Or is it possible to have a template on the google apps account which we then can transform on open?
I hope I'm a bit clear of what we would like to achieve, but in case I'm not; do feel free to ask me more questions.

I hope to hear from you all!

Kind Regards

Comment: You can do both, create it from scratch or have a template. I think the later is better, as it is more "comfortable" to change the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question relates more to a global appreciation of Google Apps than a script question... I'm not sure I should be answering here...
As a personal opinion I guess documents would be the best tool to get what you want. You'll have to create a couple of templates with personalization fields that a script would fill in with the 'logged user' data.
The document and doclist api are quite powerful and could also classify the created docs in folders and manage how they are eventually shared among users.
Depending on your abilities in javascript coding it can be anything between quite easy and really hard to build up ... :-)